# JavaScript function not working with onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the problem(if you can call it so), every time i write JS that includes functions it doesn't work. I know it's related to spaces, line-breaks or sth like that. Maybe I don't know the rule or the syntax. i'm using sublime text3(if it's related). And i will be thankful if you explain the reason to me so i won't be facing this problem ever again.  here is a code that doesn't work on my computer

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("circle").onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("circle").style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code, but if that `<script>` block appears *before* the element with id "circle" appears in the HTML, then it won't work.

Comment: I recommend you to post the whole code.

Comment: Following on from what @Pointy has said, you can check that the document has loaded before running your script. Use something like document.readyState === "complete"

Comment: thanks alot  all,it solved my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the element with the ID "circle" has the onclick function as one of its properties? you can check the property list with the dir function that is on the console.

```
console.dir(document.getElementById("circle"));
```

The dir is not for production though. It does come in handy in development and debugging.

[MDN Console.dir()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir)